# Center a div with text inside of a rotated div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to rotate a div and I want it to cover all of the body's width. So I tried setting the width to 120% (apparently 100% wasn't enough). The problem with that "solution" however is that I can't center the div inside of it correctly. How should I solve that?

Here is the code I've tried to use:

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
.rotation {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  width: 120%;
  height: 500px;
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: -50px;
}
.wrapper {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  transform: rotate(5deg);
}
```

```html
 <h1>Some title</h1>

<div class="rotation">
  <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Heading</h1>

    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo quaerat, dolore quod cum ea rerum asperiores cupiditate esse harum. Voluptatibus soluta fuga, beatae quod dolorem, veniam sint ab non laboriosam.</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fvtw7cc5/)**

Comment: Do you have a reference image of how you would like it to look? For example, what do you mean by "center [...] correctly"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can I ask why you're rotating the whole element and then rotating again the text element inside?

Instead I would suggest using a pseudo (`::before` or `::after`) element, it gives you more control over the background and means you're not rotating text twice.

Here's a JSFiddle with an example for you: https://jsfiddle.net/8nkz1278/1/

Comment: I didn't even think about this. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Correct the suggestion of @Andi North. if you wanna that the wrapper always get the height of the viewport you have 2 solutions or js or css3. I suggest css3.

With vw/vh, we can size elements to be relative to the size of the viewport. The vw/vh units are interesting in that 1 unit reflects 1/100th the width of the viewport. To make an element the full width of the viewport, for example, you'd set it to width:100vw.

in you case just add in wrapper element 'height:95vh;'

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  background-color: yellow;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.rotation {
  position: relative;
  display: table;
  height: 500px;
}

.rotation::after {
  top: 0;
  left: -10%;
  content: '';
  position: absolute; /* Bring below content */
  background: lightblue;
  z-index: 1; /* Bring below content */
  transform: rotate(-5deg);
  width: 120%;
  height: 100%;
}

.wrapper {
  position: relative;/* Bring above background shape */
  z-index: 2; /* Bring above background shape */
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  height:95vh;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h1>Some title</h1>
 
 <div class="rotation">
  <div class="wrapper">
   <h1>Heading</h1>

   <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quo quaerat, dolore quod cum ea rerum asperiores cupiditate esse harum. Voluptatibus soluta fuga, beatae quod dolorem, veniam sint ab non laboriosam.</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Cheers!!!